# Active directory filter to get all users on several AD locations without using groups

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm required to use AD for authorization to some online tools to ease software development across three countries in a big international company.

The tools AD/LDAP section have one line to specify a BASE DN, and another line to apply a user filter.

The default user filter is: (&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*))

The people that I need to reach are located at these AD locations:

1. MyCompany.com/AAA/EMA/RS/Aarhus/Accounts
2. MyCompany.com/BBB/AMR/RS/Atlanta/Accounts
3. MyCompany.com/CCC/AP/COR/Xian/Accounts

Each of the Account entries contains 4-5 deeper layers, and I need all of those people.

If I just set the BASE DN as **DC=MyCompany,DC=com** (which is what I believe it should be) I have more than 250000 users returned, of which only about 2000 should have access. :-(
My tools cache the entries, and it takes pretty long time to synchronize. :-(

I'd like to use a more specific filter to more specific target the locations.

I've tried all kinds of things, searched high and low and also asked both the tool developers and our IT department about how to do this, but have not found anything remotely useable.

I believe the filter should be something along the lines of the following - except I now know the memberOf check on membership of a group, not a hierarchy location in the AD

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(sAMAccountName=*)
  (|
    (memberOf:=OU=Accounts,OU=Aarhus,OU=RS,OU=EMA,OU=AAA,DC=MyCompany,DC=com)
    (memberOf:=OU=Accounts,OU=Atlanta,OU=RS,OU=AMR,OU=BBB,DC=MyCompany,DC=com)
    (memberOf:=OU=Accounts,OU=Xian,OU=COR,OU=AP,OU=CCC,DC=MyCompany,DC=com)
  )
)
```

And just to clarify, it's not possible for me to create (and keep updated) a group of all the people and sub-locations that should have access.

I'm eagerly awaiting your suggestions...

Note: This is my first exposure to AD/LDAP, so I probably overlooked something in this explanation - please try to fill in the blanks. Thanks.

Comment: Also of note, `memberOf` only matches on direct membership. If you want recursive matching (nested groups) you'll need to use [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks @jscott, I was aware of the limitation to `memberOf` to only match direct membership and had tried to use the `memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941` to also add nested members...  But it seems not relevant to include that info, since I have to find a method to use AD hierarchical structure instead of groups.

Comment: I do not believe you can accomplish your goal with a single search base and a single LDAP filter. You would need some manner of identifying the target users besides their OU. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9187868/260545

Comment: @jscott Thank you for the link. So it seems like the only option is to have a group with all the members.... but as far as I can find online, it's also not possible to create a group with dynamic members based on OU. :-(   I found a few mentions of the possibility to make a dynamic distribution list based on OU, but then I couldn't find a method to check for membership of a distribution list to use in the filter. It looks like this was deliberately made difficult! :-(

Comment: you could maybe check the source ip of the client querying the application, and using the subnets info (also in ldap, in the CN=Subnets,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,dc=your,dc=domain container), and depending on what subnet they are on, you search one of the Atlanta/Aarhus/Xian containers. It could be worth a try.